# Blank string returned in the below Code in Android

Tags: java, android, opennlp

So i am using OpenNLP but I am using it for android.
This code always returns blank string ,I have been stuck at it for days now.

This method should be able to identify the names from the string i send to it.

```
 public  String  findName( String string) throws IOException  {

                Log.e("ARTIFICIAL INTELLIGENCE CLASS",  string);
// checked the logcat,string received is not null
                AssetManager  am=context.getAssets();
                String returnedName ="";
                InputStream modelInToken = am.open("en-token.bin");

                InputStream modelIn = am.open("en-ner-person.bin");;

                try {

                    //1. convert sentence into tokens

                        TokenizerModel modelToken = new TokenizerModel(modelInToken); 
                        Tokenizer tokenizer = new TokenizerME(modelToken);  
                        String tokens[] = tokenizer.tokenize(string);

                        TokenNameFinderModel model = new TokenNameFinderModel(modelIn);
                        NameFinderME nameFinder = new NameFinderME(model);

                        Span nameSpans[] = nameFinder.find(tokens);

                        //find probabilities for names
                        double[] spanProbs = nameFinder.probs(nameSpans);

                        //3. print names
                        for( int i = 0; i<nameSpans.length; i++) {
                    Log.e("Span: ",            nameSpans[i].toString());
                    Log.e("Probability is: " , " "+spanProbs[i]);
                    Log.e("Covered text is: ", tokens[nameSpans[i].getStart()] + " " + tokens[nameSpans[i].getStart()+1]);
                    Log.e("Yes","OH yes");

                    returnedName= nameSpans[0].toString();
                }           
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e("ARTIFICIAL INTELLIGENCE CLASS", "error is here");
                }
                finally {
                      try { if (modelInToken != null) modelInToken.close(); } catch (IOException e){
                          Log.e("ARTIFICIAL INTELLIGENCE CLASS", "error is here 1");
                      };
                      try { if (modelIn != null) modelIn.close(); } catch (IOException e){
                          Log.e("ARTIFICIAL INTELLIGENCE CLASS", "error is here 2");
                      };
                }
            if(returnedName==null){
                    return "No name";}
                    else{
                        return returnedName;
                    }


            }
```

this is how i am  calling the method.

```
name =  findName(string);`
```

Comment: can you post logcat here.

Comment: Add the stacktrace please.

Comment: Why arent you logging catch (Exception ex ) ?

Comment: it is just a simple nullpointer ex...if i add stack trace it will become more confusing..anyways i have added it

Comment: @BoradHardik done..please check

Comment: @Jens done ,please check

Comment: @SercanOzdemir done,the error remains the same

Comment: what is in Line 76 in Your ArtificalIntelligence class?

Comment: which one is that line ? 

05-11 11:17:33.713: W/System.err(30204):    at com.example.chatbox.ArtificalIntelligence.handleLine(ArtificalIntelligence.java:76)

Comment: You are getting an exception while trying to create a new String, when findName method throws an exception and returns null. But you have to log catch parth as:

Log.e("ARTIFICIAL INTELLIGENCE CLASS", ex);

So copy yellow logs that indicate exception to here.. I mean just log the exception.

Comment: @SercanOzdemir i made the change as suggested by the other guy,now i am getting a blank string.

Answer (score 1):

Your default return is null, if You want to return a String I think You should make a String at the top of Your method:

```
    String returnedName ="";
```

and after the loop:

```
       returnedName = nameSpans[i].toString();
```

and then, avoid a NullPointerException where You use the Method, for example:

```
      private void getName(){

       String name="";
       try{

         name = findName("Mr.Coolice");
         if(name==null){
           name = "NoName";
         }

      } catch(IOException){


      }
```

### EDIT

if You follow my example and then You use:

```
  name = new String(findName(string));
```

is wrong, it must be:

```
 name = findName(string);
```

### EDIT 2

Now we are coming to the solution :) . You write:

```
  xyz=ai.handleLine(et.getText().toString()) ;
```

What I think is, that et is an editText, right? Then You should avoid this and get sure the string from Your editText is not null:

```
     String editTextString = et.getText().toString();

     if(editTextString!=null){
        ai.handleLine(editTextString);
     }
```

Comment: no no,that was the code i was using earlier ....although yes ,i am returning only null now....let me check ...

Comment: what do You want to return in that method?

Comment: the first name
 return nameSpans[i].toString();

Comment: it is hidden in the for loop

Comment: Just saw the update
no,as soon as return statement is encountered ,it doesn't proceed any further and hence it won't go the return null; statement.

Comment: I think You are going a little bit wrong with the cause of Your exception. The stacktrace tells You that there is a problem in Your ArtificalIntelligence class in Line 76, so You should post this line and the important part of code too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77480/discussion-between-amit0191-and-opiatefuchs).